# Resizing an `IList<T>`

Tags: c#, comparative-review, vectors, extension-methods

I need to resize an `IList<T>`. I have written two versions and would like to
have a review of those. I am particularly interested on which of the two is to
be preferred but grateful for all other advice as well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Foo
{
    public static class IListExtensions
    {
        public static void Resize<T>(this IList<T> list, int size)
        {
            if (list == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(list));

            if (size < 0)
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(size));

            while (list.Count > size)
                list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
        }

        public static void Resize2<T>(this IList<T> list, int size)
        {
            if (list == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(list));

            if (size < 0)
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(size));

            var tmp = list.Take(size).ToList();
            list.Clear();
            list.AddRange(tmp);
        }

        public static void AddRange<T>(this IList<T> list, IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            if (list == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(list));

            if (items == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(items));

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                list.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IList<string> words = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
            words.Resize(1);

            IList<string> words2 = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
            words2.Resize2(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _I need to resize an `IList<T>`_ - but why? It can resize itself and removing items from it with `.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1)` is not resizing. It all depends on it internal implementation which should not be any of your concerns. Do you have any problems with it or why are you _resizing_ it?

Comment: Really strange post. You can take a look at one of the `IList<T>` implementations – `List<T>` – on [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) and see that neither `RemoveAt` nor `Clear` don't resize internal array. Or "resizing" in your undestanding is just taking first n elements?

Comment: @t3chb0t I have three words in `IList<string> words` and want a list with one word. Why not? How can a `IList<T>`resize itself? Why is removing items different from resizing? (Appart from that I should have called it `Shrink` instead.) I do not care about the internal implementation, I just want to resize from three words to one.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I feel there's a language barrier here - what you refer to isn't *necessarily* resizing so much as just *removing* elements. (Technically that doesn't *have* to change the size of the `IList<T>`, but it's possible that for some scenarios it will.)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Paparazzi Your link is for `List<T>` this question is about `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should throw the appropriate exception:

```
if (list == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));

if (size < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(size));
```

In general remember that first argument of `ArgumentException` isn't the parameter name but the error message.

Both versions are equally *good* (or *bad*) unless you have a specific usage scenario and some performance requirements, I can't really comment on that from a generic point of view.

Just one note: you remove tail items from the list but there are good chances (it depends on the effective collection type you're using) that size in memory won't decrease (for example with `List<T>` you have to call `TrimExcess()`. What does it mean? That, maybe, `Resize()` isn't the most clear name ever because callers may expect a different behavior.

You may be inspired by LINQ implementation and check for common cases, for example `List<T>`.

```
public static void Resize<T>(this IList<T> list, int size)
{
    if (list == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));

    if (size < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(size));

    if (list is List<T> genericList)
    {
        genericList.RemoveRange(size, list.Count - size);
    }
    else
    {
        while (list.Count > size)
            list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

The same is true for `AddRange()` which doesn't need to be manually implemented when list is `List<T>`.

**Edit**: EBrown noted in [comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174293/resizing-an-ilistt/174295#comment330717_174295) that this *optimization* may be unnecessary (and then counterproductive because it greatly hurts readability); I agree, if you need it or not is specific to your usage scenario and you should decide after after a microbenchmark with real world data.

A very quick benchmark (release build, one warm-up round, average of 100 executions) gave this (measure is in number of **ticks** then compare them cum grano salis):

[image: Benchmark for small number of items]

And:

[image: Benchmark for bigger number of items]

Label "N to M" means "list of N elements trimmed to M element". Strings are 12 characters strings.

That said, performance is not always *required* or needed, especially when sacrificing readability.

Comment: I must say this whole resizing thing is very suspicious and highly questionable.

Comment: Well, it's not that uncommon task to cut the tail of a list (especially when working with old code which has not been _ported_ to be LINQ friendly).

Comment: if `size < count` then `genericList.Capacity = size;` will error. It even says so in the docs. You could do `genericList.RemoveRange(size, list.Count - size);` instead though.

Comment: Tnx @RobH, you're right. Fixed.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Personally, I think this is a bad solution, because now you've added *unnecessary branching*, and the method became more complex for something that *may* be a performance advantage, but also may not be.

Comment: @EBrown I agree that, generally speaking, any optimization is premature without any evidence (that's why I mentioned we can't really judge without a specific usage scenario and _real-world_ profiling) however...LINQ methods are _full_ of this kind of _optimizations_ then it makes me think that it's an usage pattern really really common and it is worth of its special handling.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Except that OP is working with *small* collections of words. The overhead added by branching and testing the type *of a generic parameter* (that usually means you're doing something wrong) is almost *certainly* going to be higher than any performance impact the optimized method might have (if it's optimized). There's just too much speculation here for me.

Comment: @EBrown _small_ collection of words is a speculation, to me. OP might shed some light on this.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti OP specifically mentions 3 words to 1 in the question comments. And I'm not against the idea in general, just this terrible implementation. *Just build a new overload for pete's sake.* Handling the situation like this is just plain **wrong**. The compiler can do the branching and make the decision.

Comment: @EBrown _"I need to resize an IList<T>."_ (ignoring the misleading `Resize()` name), I do not see any mention to size and usage pattern. Overloaded version? Overloaded methods are resolved at compile-time, we then drop the _advantage_ to make this decision at run-time (and if it was known at compile-time outside any fictional testing code then he didn't even need this method)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I'm not interested in continuing this debate. I think this is a *terrible* idea, and I'm going to stand by that opinion. If you like it, *great*, more power to you. I would prefer to *not* have to spend the extra minute or so when I revisit this in 6-12 months to have to determine why `List<T>` is handled specially. "Oh, that's right, it *might* be faster like this." I *get* it, this *could* be faster, it's more "clever", but on the chance that it's neither of those, it adds bloat and extra thought required to analyze what *should* be a simple, concise, tight method.

Comment: @EBrown yes, I see we won't _convince_ each other here; I made my choice according to the _way_ used in LINQ (with the assumption that they analyzed a huge amount of real world code). Without more details from OP well...thank you for this discussion!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I can see *why* you're looking at it like that, but I just feel the overhead is unnecessary. I've always respected your answers (especially on Stack Overflow) and still do, but I just can not and will not back this one up. :/

Comment: @EBrown it's OK, to debate is an important part of code reviews, I think. I will be happy to delete this if OP will clarify from which point of view we should take it, to keep code simple is more important than any doubtfully _clever_ optimization.